# Iniliziating formal parameters can't be used in factory constructors

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying add singleton pattern in my class but i receive `Iniliziating formal parameters can't be used in factory constructors` error. Here is what i tried:

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  final String email;
  final String token;
  final bool wordtestCompleted;


  User.forJson({this.email, this.token, this.wordtestCompleted})
  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);



  static final User _singleton = User._internal();

  factory User({this.email, this.token, this.wordtestCompleted}) {
    return _singleton;
  }

  User._internal();
}
```

how to fix it?

Comment: How do you intend to create this single singleton? What values are you passing in for email, token, etc? And how? Are you trying to instantiate the singleton from a piece of JSON, which, of course, you'd only do once? So, what's the use case for this singleton?

Comment: @RichardHeap the main purpose of this class is it receiving data from da api and parse it. So I want to use this class as Singleton after parsed the json string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntactic sugar of using `this.` in constructor parameters to initialize members works only in normal constructors, not in `factory` constructors. (A `factory` constructor has no `this` object!)

You instead will need to manually forward your `factory` constructor's arguments to an actual constructor.  For example:

```dart
class User {
  static User _singleton;

  final String email;
  final String token;
  final bool wordtestCompleted;

  User._internal({this.email, this.token, this.wordtestCompleted});

  factory User({String email, String token, bool wordtestCompleted}) {
    return _singleton ??= User._internal(
      email: email,
      token: token,
      wordtestCompleted: wordtestCompleted,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ty for your reply. how should i call to current instance from another class @jamesdlin

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  In the example I provided, another class can use the `factory` constructor and will always get back the same instance.

Comment: in kotlin for example i call User.getCurrentInstance to get same instance. but i don't know how to call it in dart in this code

Comment: You could simply add a `static` getter to access `_singleton` (and require that callers use it only after `User` has been constructed once).